# React JS Ajax call

Tags: ajax, reactjs

I am building a reactredux dashboard application. I am from angular background so i am getting confuse here. What i really want to do is when i am in dashboard page i want to fetch data from api to show data in graphs. But the thing is here an action is not involved. Whenever i am in dashboard page i want to trigger that API to fetch data. Where should i make that request- In action or in the dashboard component. What is the best approach? In angular i just used to do ng-init from the view .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`componentDidMount()` method is a good place to fetch data either of the component or enclosing one. If the component is redux aware probably should  fetch in an action, and trigger that action when loading the component (same action that 'opens' the dashboard). 
Generally speaking there is no best approach and it is up to you to decide, one of the beauties of react it is not opinionated about your code structure and solves one thing only (how to render view from `state` and `props` that is)

Comment: Dashboard opens through routing and not by an action. How to fetch data  from  API when user open or route to /dashboard.?